# file path unresolved in VS code

Tags: angular

I am trying to import component in the routing file of angular.

Here is the Directory/file structure :

[image]

and here is the import statement which gives me an error of `String literal expected.ts(1141)`

```
import { HeaderComponent } from ./common/header.component;
```

Have also tried with the below statement, but didn't work.

```
import { HeaderComponent } from ./common/header/header.component;
```

Can someone point out what went wrong here, please?

app.module.ts

```
import { HeaderComponent } from './common/header/header.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Try `import { HeaderComponent } from './common/header.component';` with `'...'`

Comment: wrap path in single quotes

Comment: @pzaenger - it gives me "Expression expected.ts(1109)" and "Property 'component' does not exist on type 'RegExp'" errors.

Comment: @Supercool. - by doing so, it gives me "Cannot find module './common/header.component'". I have also updated app.module.ts statement in question.

Comment: Its a app-routing.module.ts file.

Comment: Guys, this has been resolved now. import { HeaderComponent } from './common/header/header.component';

Comment: did you write export class HeaderComponent?

Comment: try restart vs code and do not write import  statement and just write name of component as u did in app.module you will get suggestion (or can use auto import module) from vs code to import this component and that will automatically do for you.